# How to compare and extract arrays inside of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a program that needs to compare different birthday dates in an array, and the array is like this:

```
birthdays = [1, [11,2], 2, [2,4], 3, [11,2], 4, [3,5], 5, [6,7], 6, [3,5], 7, [8,9]..]
```

The even index stores the number of student, and the odd positions store their birthday date in the form of an array[month, day]. I need to return an array of number of students who have unique birthday dates(their birthday dates only appeared once in the array).

Here is my effort so far:

```
function find(birthdays) {
    let array2 = birthdays.slice();
    let unique_arr = [];
    let element_comp;
    for (let i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i++) {
        birthdays.splice(i,1)//birthdays
        array2.splice(i+1,1)//numbers
      }
      
      for(let i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i++){
          element_comp = birthdays[i];
          for(let j = 0; j < birthdays.length; j++){
              if(i !== j &&element_comp.toString == birthdays[j].toString){
                  break;
              }

              if(j === birthdays.length - 1){
                  unique_arr.push(array2[i])
              }
          }
      }
      return unique_arr;
}
```

My idea is to break the array into to two sub-arrays, one stores the numbers and the other one stores the birthday dates. Then I compared the element of the birthday date array one by one to see if they are unique. If I find a same date, I break out of the inner and start to compare the next one, otherwise if the inner index reaches the end of the array I stores the element of the number array of the same index into another array that will be returned

```
Expected Result:[2, 5, 7...]
```

But it didn't work as expected because it would break out of the array each time and never store the element. Please explain to me where I did wrong, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with dictiory. without having nested loop

loop on element and see if month and date combination `month_date` exist in dict append the students to it else create a new key with `month_date` and append to dict with value of array of current student

after this loop complete you can loop over dict key values and and see if any key having single value then take those values.

```
function find(birthdays) {
    let unique_dates = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i+=2) {
        let key = `${birthdays[i+1][0]}_${birthdays[i+1][1]}`

        if (!(key in unique_dates)) {
            unique_dates[key] = []
        }

        unique_dates[key].push(birthdays[i])
    }

    let unique_arr = [];
    for (let unique_date in unique_dates){
        if (unique_dates[unique_date].length == 1) {
            unique_arr.push(unique_dates[unique_date][0])
        }
    }
  return unique_arr;
}
```